# How to get access time in inotify

Tags: c, linux, inotify

In `inotify` I see the following opcodes:

```
const agnosticEvents = unix.IN_MOVED_TO | unix.IN_MOVED_FROM |
        unix.IN_CREATE | unix.IN_ATTRIB | unix.IN_MODIFY |
        unix.IN_MOVE_SELF | unix.IN_DELETE | unix.IN_DELETE_SELF
```

Is there a way to get when a file was opened/accessed? For example, if I typed in `cat <file>` or `open <file>` or `vim <file>`. How would I get that event to flow-through, or is it not possible?

Comment: you can get this information using `stat` st_*time https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html but you probably know. For `inotify` I don't know. Is your question for inotify exclusively? Or to handle a usecase?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL well, I need to set up a listener to see whenever a file was accessed -- I was hoping it was possible with inotify. There are millions of files, so It's not too feasible to do grep/find/ls/stat or whatever (actually, that's the current way I'm doing it and it takes about 2 days to run)

Comment: @David542 `inotify` does have `IN_ACCESS`. Isn't that what you're after?

Comment: stat is very fast with listdir, are you sure ?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL yea it's not about `stat` it's about running `find` or `ls` on millions of files and millions of directories.

Comment: @P.P I think so, thanks for pointing that out, let me test...

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Listing directories and calling `stat(2)` would at least 2 system calls per file (readdir and stat). Which is going to be really slow for millions of files.

Comment: if all files are in the same directory its only 1 sys call for the whole folder. NB: I am not here to say that its better than inotify

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL no unfortunately...probably a million folders how things are currently structured on the volume.